# Console.log prints the cart but can't bind it to the html. ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

What am I doing wrong?
As you can see the console.log prints the output fine but I can't seem to see it on the webpage.

> get-cart.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Cart } from 'src/app/models/cartModel';
import { UsersService } from 'src/app/services/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-get-one-cart',
  templateUrl: './get-one-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-one-cart.component.css']
})
export class GetOneCartComponent implements OnInit {
  cart: Cart;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UsersService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.userService.getCartForUser(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.cart = data;
      console.log(this.cart)
    });
  }

}
```

> get-cart.html

```html
<div class="content-box">
    <a routerLink="/users">
        <button>Back</button>
    </a>
    <div *ngIf="cart">
        <h2>{{cart._id}}</h2>
        <p>{{cart.userId}}</p>
        <div *ngFor="let product of cart.products">
            <p>{{product.productId}}</p>
            <p>{{product.quantity}}</p>
            <p>{{product.price}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[console.log and webpage outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmUDl.png)

Comment: You should try to review your types. It seems like the data coming from the API call is an Array and not of type `Cart`. You are trying to access properties like '_id' and 'userId' of this array.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer! I just had to set

```
await Cart.find
```

to

```
await Cart.findOne
```